# How to create a growth column or a share column in an SQL Server 2008 Cube Development?

Tags: olap

I have a huge amount of sales data starting from 2000 till 2009. I want to calculate growth on 2009 sales versus 2008 sales.

I also want to calculate share of each product in any particular year or month.

Best Regards

Wajih

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking straight MDX you could do something like:

Code Snippet
(

Sum( MTD( [Date].[Calendar].[Date].[21.10.2008] ),
       [Measures].[Sales] )

-

Sum( MTD( ParallelPeriod( [Date].[Calendar].[Year], 1,
                            [Date].[Calendar].[Date].[21.10.2008] ) ),
       [Measures].[Sales] )

)

/
  Sum( MTD( ParallelPeriod( [Date].[Calendar].[Year], 1,
                            [Date].[Calendar].[Date].[21.10.2008] ) ),
       [Measures].[Sales] )

You could also make it a KPI value using the KPI tab in VS Business Intelligence Dev Studio.
It all depends on how you want to reference it (i.e., in Excel 2007 or through some third-party reporting tool).